# Login form validation on node server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm creating a login page in Javascript. I have a post method in my `server.js` that checks if the password is correct.

I also have a `main.js` file where I do the validation (if the password is long enough etc.). I want to make the form validation and therefore I have created an array called `messages`. I want to use the function `messages.join` so that the content gets pushed into a div.

The code below wasn't in `server.js` but in the `main.js`. How can I get the thing below into my server?

const userErrorElement = document.getElementById("user-error");

```
let userMessages = [];
if (username.value === "" || username.value === null) {
    userMessages.push("Name field can't be empty");
}
if (userMessages.length > 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    errorElement.innerText = messages.join(", ")
}
```

Btw, I need to have it on my server because I need to check the password which is in the server.js file.

Or is there another way to get the validation error messages below the input (sth like 'password too long' or 'password isn't correct')? I want to do it on my server so I can check if the password is wrong I send this error message.

```
if (credentials["Password"] == password) {
  req.session.username = username;
  res.redirect('/chat.html');
}
else {
  //put error message into the div / an other way to say that the password is wrong
  res.redirect('/index.html');
}
```

Some warning like this (sorry its german but it means I have to type in my email address or cellphone number)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the pattern you're describing isn't possible because of the way clients and servers work :)

The server can't change anything on the page - it can't change the `<div>`, for example.  That's why there's Javascript on the page: it stands in between the server response and the page render. So, you have to return information from the server to the client Javascript.

For the validation information you're asking about (e.g. 'password is too long'), you have two options: send the password back to the server, or write some Javascript on the client that checks it. Most applications do both.

The client check is faster, but malicious users can get around it very easily.  The server check is slower and more effort, but is harder to attack. Good luck!

---

Sample server-side validation function (a little bit silly, intentionally):

```
const validate = (str) => {
    const errors = [];

    if (str.length < 892) {
        errors.push('Your password must be at least 892 characters');
    }

    if (str[0] !== 'Z') {
        errors.push('The first character of your password must be "Z"');
    }
};
```

This would live on the server. The client sends a potential password to the server.  You take that password, run it through this function, and return the array of errors back to the client.  Also, if you like, you could change the [status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) of the response from the server to show success/failure.

Then, on the client, you take the response, [parse it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), and show the error messages in the `<div>`.

(Of course, there's libraries and stuff that handle this for you, but you'll still need to have built this stuff so you know what you're doing.)

---

> what do you mean by sending it back to the client

The `res.redirect()` calls in your original question are sending a `res`ponse back to the client.  You can send anything you want. If you're using express, the call is `res.send()`, so [have a look at the docs](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res) to see what all is available.

Comment: I do send the credentials to the server and on the server I check if they are correct. How can I validate them then? Or how can I do it like on the screenshot?

Comment: @Codeopold when you send it to the server make the validation and send it back to the client with the error message, the client will be listening to the response sent by the server. this is a typically done using AJAX.

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean by sending it back to the client? Can you give me a code example?

Comment: You probably have to write your own validation function. I'll update my answer with a code example.